# Reduce function returning NaN when pulling object from array - MongoDB database, React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }],
});
```

I am attempting to loop through my database entries, pull the 'newBalance' out from each object in the balance array, and then reduce / sum them together.

However, it is returning 'NaN' - and I can't figure out why.

Here is my Axios call to get the data:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get("/api/fetch/fetchDebtCards")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        debts: response.data
      })
      console.log(this.state.debts.balance.newBalance)
    })
  }
```

The console log in there successfully retrieves the database entries.

And here is my reduce function:

```
const sumBalance = this.state.debts.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
          return (
            previousValue + currentValue.balance.newBalance
          )
        }, 0)
```

You can see, I'm attempting to tap into 'balance.newBalance' to access the newBalance within each of the balance objects.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: My console log, with two entries. What I want to do is get the newBalance array.length -1 from these, and sum them together by reducing.

> [Log] Array
>
> 0 Object
>
> balance: [{_id: "5fbbddd1077c56000828973c", balanceDate:
> "2020-11-23T16:05:36.124Z", newBalance: 400}]
>
> 1 Object
>
> balance: [{_id: "5fbc06f58b2f98000865df54", balanceDate:
> "2020-11-23T19:01:07.789Z", newBalance: 300}] (1)

Comment: if ```currentValue.balance.newBalance``` has any NaN in it then you will get NaN as a result of the reduction.  Maybe try returning a constant "1" in the retrun statement to either rule in or out this as the potential cause

Comment: There’s figures in every entry, there has to be. So it’ll be because it’s not pulling the entries.

Comment: `this.state.debts` should be an array so you can use reduce. but following to your console.log it's not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if "console.log(this.state.debts.balance.newBalance)" works then debts is not an array, how are you using map on debts then? Map can only be used on arrays.

I'm not sure how your debts object/array is exactly. Maybe a log of it would be helpful.

If it is an array, then this might work.

```
const sumBalance = this.state.debts.map(x => x.balance).flat().reduce((a,b) => a + b.newBalance, 0)
```

whereas if it's an object, then this might work

```
const sumBalance = this.state.debts.balance.reduce((a,b) => a+b.newBalance, 0)
```

If none of these work, just log "this.state.debts" and let us see what you have there.

Edit: Ok so you only need the last values of the balance arrays (the latest balance), something like this?

```
const sumBalance = this.state.debts.map(x => x.balance[x.balance.length-1].newBalance).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
```

Comment: Hey, I will update my original post with my console log... The first one of these didn't work - the crucial bit is, I'm not trying to reduce the 'newBalance' arrays, but all of the balances, and specifically the newBalance within them if that makes sense?

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: Well according to your structure the first answer should work, what output does it give you?

Comment: Okay, I think I’ve figured it out... And it’s my fault. So ‘balance’ is an array of objects. Your first function returns 3000 - which is progress, but what I actually want is to pull the last figure from the balance array, and do that for all of my database entries; then sum them together. I took the array of values out of each log; as there was 7/8 in each of them. So it’d be something like x.balance[balance.length - 1] I think...

Comment: Working spot on after the edit. Thanks a lot for your help!